# Proxychains, Tor, SSH and Danted. Connection denied

Tags: socks, tor, proxychains

I'm trying to setup proxychains on Kali like this :

```
User > Tor > SOCKS5 > Out
```

I've created my SOCKS5 server with danted running on port 1080.
I setup an SSH connection on my Kali distrib :

```
ssh -NfD 1080 user@address
```

And I'm able to connect to the SOCKS5 server without trouble.
Same when I'm trying to connect to Tor network.

But when I try to connect to Tor AND to the SOCKS5 server, I get a denied error :

```
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<>-127.0.0.1:1080-<--denied
```

So I tried to allow connections from any IP address in dante, I'm not sure if it's right :

```
logoutput: /var/log/dante.log

internal: 127.0.0.1 port = 1080
external: venet0
method: username none
user.notprivileged: nobody

client pass {
  from: 0.0.0.0/0 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
  protocol: tcp udp
}
pass {
  from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
  protocol: tcp udp
}
```

Any idea where it could come from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer to my question and for a visibility purpose I think responding is better than editing.

So I wanted to use Tor and a SOCKS5 proxy at the same time using proxychains.
There are two ways to achieve that :

**With dante server**

Dante server is a SOCKS5 server (and client) with lots of options I don't know yet but will learn soon I hope.

So first you install dante-server :

```
wget https://www.inet.no/dante/files/dante-1.4.1.tar.gz
tar xvf dante-1.4.1.tar.gz
cd dante-1.4.1
./configure
make && make install

#This is my launch script you can use yours obviously
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71868038/sockd
mv sockd /etc/init.d/sockd
chmod +x /etc/init.d/sockd
update-rc.d sockd defaults

wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71868038/sockd.conf
mv sockd.conf /etc/
```

You can edit your conf as you want, for example to block all the requests except from your IP address. More info [here](https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/1.4.x/config/index.html).
Don't forget to change the IP address of your server in the config file !

Now that your SOCKS5 server is ready and works, you can use it along with tor thanks to proxychains. Just add your server in the config file :

```
strict_chain
proxy_dns
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000
socks4 127.0.0.1 9050
socks5 1.2.3.4 1080
```

Start tor and enjoy :

```
service tor start
proxychains iceweasel
```

---

**With an SSH tunnel**

Simpler solution.

You will need tor, torsocks and ssh

```
apt-get install torsocks
service tor start
torsocks ssh -NfD 1080 1.2.3.4
proxychains iceweasel
```

Configuration of proxychains :

```
strict_chain
proxy_dns
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000
socks5 127.0.0.1 1080
```

What you do is you tunnel an SSH connection to your server after going through tor service (torsocks do that, I don't really know how it works yet. I'll edit if I figure out).

And then :

```
proxychains iceweasel
```

If someone needs more in-depth explanations just ask ;)